# Space between headers and title Content in ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, header-footer

I was looking all day for some alternative in ToC space between header and title Content. I found `\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip`, but it's useless in my case cause I already use package `\fancyhd` and `\tocloft`. I somewhere read that fancy doesn't like tocloft and code `\cftaftertoctitleskip` etc. are useless.

I am using two side doc. report, a4 paper and babel czech. I am curious about `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-10pt}}` if exists some similar code that can control spacing between title Content and header.

There is some example my code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,     % velikost zakladniho pisma
               a4paper,  % papir A4
               twoside,  % jednostranny tisk (default)
               czech     % originalni jazyk  cz
               ]{report} % dokument tridy zprava
% Nastaveni obsahu
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}  
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt} 
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{2.5pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{2.5pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{4.5em}{3.5em}


\begin{document} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy} 
\addtocontents{toc}
  \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots}}}%
}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-10pt}}
\end{document}
```

Adding photo for better understanding my problem.
Thanks everyone for responding :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the negative space before the title if the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,    % velikost zakladniho pisma
               a4paper,  % papir A4
               twoside,  % jednostranny tisk (default)
               czech     % originalni jazyk  cz
               ]{report} % dokument tridy zprava
% Nastaveni obsahu
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt} 
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{2.5pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{2.5pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{4.5em}{3.5em}



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace*{-4cm}Contents}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\section{title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamite,

This doesn't work. It has do nothing with spacing.`\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace*{-4cm}Contents}`

**EDIT:**
This is code with titlesec

> `\usepackage{titlesec}
>   \titleformat*{\section}{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright} 
>   \titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries} 
>   \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
>   \titlespacing*{\section}
>   {0pt}{4.5ex plus 1ex minus .1ex}{3.3ex plus .1ex} 
>   \titlespacing*{\subsection}
>   {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .1ex}{2.3ex plus .1ex}
>   \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
>   {0pt}{3.0ex plus 1ex minus .0ex}{1.7ex plus .1ex}`

Comment: Do you use other packages that you omit  in your question?

Comment: Yeah. I think maybe package titlesec could be a problem. I have normal classic package like modern, hyperref...

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to your question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I added to EDIT comment above.

Comment: Btw, can you tell me how to write correctly code on stackexchange? I cannot fullfil yellow color on \usepackage etc. Thank you very much.